# Singleton has same address in multiple processes, but behaves like separate objects

Tags: python, multiprocessing, singleton, memory-address

I figured instantiating a singleton across different processes would result in different objects, so that the singleton would only be local to its own process. To validate this, I wrote a test:

```
def v1():
    def keep_receiving():
        while True:
            print("from rec_proc: ", MessagePipe())
            print(MessagePipe().recv())

    def keep_sending():
        for i in range(3):
            print("from send_proc:", MessagePipe())
            MessagePipe().send(text=f"test {i + 1}")
            time.sleep(1)

    send_proc = Process(target=keep_sending)
    send_proc.start()

    rec_proc = Process(target=keep_receiving)
    rec_proc.start()

    send_proc.join()
```

I expected the two processes to print out objects at different memory adresses. But that is not the case:

Output:

```
from send_proc: <image_service.service.utils.message_pipe.MessagePipe object at 0x7f805e769610>
from rec_proc:  <image_service.service.utils.message_pipe.MessagePipe object at 0x7f805e769610>
from send_proc: <image_service.service.utils.message_pipe.MessagePipe object at 0x7f805e769610>
from send_proc: <image_service.service.utils.message_pipe.MessagePipe object at 0x7f805e769610>
```

As you can see, the addresses are the same.

**Question**: Why are the addresses the same if these are TWO different instances, each in its own process?

It has to be two different instances, because otherwise the line `print(MessagePipe().recv())` should print out three received messages.

When I modify the test like this, I get behavior that I would expect:

```
def v2():
    def keep_receiving(pipe):
        while True:
            print("from rec_proc: ", pipe)
            print(pipe.recv())

    def keep_sending(pipe):
        for i in range(3):
            print("from send_proc:", pipe)
            pipe.send(text=f"test {i + 1}")
            time.sleep(1)

    send_proc = Process(target=keep_sending, args=(MessagePipe(), ))
    send_proc.start()

    rec_proc = Process(target=keep_receiving, args=(MessagePipe(), ))
    rec_proc.start()

    send_proc.join()
```

```
from send_proc: <image_service.service.utils.message_pipe.MessagePipe object at 0x7f51c2dff670>
from rec_proc:  <image_service.service.utils.message_pipe.MessagePipe object at 0x7f51c2dff670>
{'text': 'test 1', 'exception': None, 'level': 20}
from rec_proc:  <image_service.service.utils.message_pipe.MessagePipe object at 0x7f51c2dff670>
from send_proc: <image_service.service.utils.message_pipe.MessagePipe object at 0x7f51c2dff670>
{'text': 'test 2', 'exception': None, 'level': 20}
from rec_proc:  <image_service.service.utils.message_pipe.MessagePipe object at 0x7f51c2dff670>
from send_proc: <image_service.service.utils.message_pipe.MessagePipe object at 0x7f51c2dff670>
{'text': 'test 3', 'exception': None, 'level': 20}
from rec_proc:  <image_service.service.utils.message_pipe.MessagePipe object at 0x7f51c2dff670>
```

The `MessagePipe` class is implemented as follows, but the implementation is not central to the question, I think.

```
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pipe


class MessagePipe:
    """This implements a multiprocessing message pipe as a singleton and is intended for passing event information
    such as log messaged and exceptions between processes.
    """

    _instance = None
    _parent_connection = None
    _child_connection = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(MessagePipe, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._parent_connection, cls._child_connection = Pipe()
        return cls._instance

    @property
    def child_connection(self):
        return self._child_connection

    @property
    def parent_connection(self):
        return self._parent_connection

    def send(self, text="", exception=None, level=logging.INFO):
        message = {
            "text": text,
            "exception": exception,
            "level": level
        }
        self.child_connection.send(message)

    def recv(self):
        return self.parent_connection.recv()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody might be able to explain this with greater detail but I believe the problem -- and there is a problem which I will explain in a moment -- is that you have to first ask how are the arguments being passed from your main process to your new subprocesses. Well, it would seem that would depend on what platform you are running under, which you neglected to specify but I can infer is one that uses *fork* to create new processes. I believe that because your platform supports forking and therefore inherits the address space (read/only, copy on write) from the main process, no special mechanism such as `pickle` is required to serialize/deserialize the arguments and *that* is why the addresses are the same.

But here's the rub: Under Windows, which does not support *fork* and will rely on `pickle` for propagating `Process` arguments, the `Message.__new__` method will be re-executed in each of the newly created processes. Not only will the singletons have their own unique addresses (unless a miracle occurs), they will be allocating their own `multiprocessing.Pipe` instances and then, of course, the application will not work at all as demonstrated below. You would be better off just passing `multiprocessing.Connection` objects to your subprocesses.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import logging
import time

class MessagePipe:
    """This implements a multiprocessing message pipe as a singleton and is intended for passing event information
    such as log messaged and exceptions between processes.
    """

    _instance = None
    _parent_connection = None
    _child_connection = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            print('__new__ is executing')
            cls._instance = super(MessagePipe, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._parent_connection, cls._child_connection = Pipe()
        return cls._instance

    @property
    def child_connection(self):
        return self._child_connection

    @property
    def parent_connection(self):
        return self._parent_connection

    def send(self, text="", exception=None, level=logging.INFO):
        message = {
            "text": text,
            "exception": exception,
            "level": level
        }
        self.child_connection.send(message)

    def recv(self):
        return self.parent_connection.recv()

def keep_receiving(pipe):
    for i in range(3):
        print("from rec_proc: ", pipe)
        print(pipe.recv())

def keep_sending(pipe):
    for i in range(3):
        print("from send_proc:", pipe)
        pipe.send(text=f"test {i + 1}")
        time.sleep(1)

def v2():
    send_proc = Process(target=keep_sending, args=(MessagePipe(), ))
    send_proc.start()

    rec_proc = Process(target=keep_receiving, args=(MessagePipe(), ))
    rec_proc.start()

    send_proc.join()
    rec_proc.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    v2()
```

Prints:

```
__new__ is executing
__new__ is executing
from send_proc: <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x00000283480705E0>
from rec_proc:  <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x00000249497A05E0>
from send_proc: <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x00000283480705E0>
from send_proc: <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x00000283480705E0>
```

`rec_proc` hangs because it is reading from a connection that nobody is writing to.

The problem can be somewhat mitigated by specifying `pickle` `__setstate__` and `__getstate__` methods for your `MessagePipe` class. This will not stop your `__new__` method from being called and creating a new `Pipe` instances in the subprocesses but it will replace them with the serialized arguments that were passed.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import logging
import time

class MessagePipe:
    """This implements a multiprocessing message pipe as a singleton and is intended for passing event information
    such as log messaged and exceptions between processes.
    """

    _instance = None
    _parent_connection = None
    _child_connection = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            print('__new__ is executing')
            cls._instance = super(MessagePipe, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._parent_connection, cls._child_connection = Pipe()
        return cls._instance

    @property
    def child_connection(self):
        return self._child_connection

    @property
    def parent_connection(self):
        return self._parent_connection

    def send(self, text="", exception=None, level=logging.INFO):
        message = {
            "text": text,
            "exception": exception,
            "level": level
        }
        self.child_connection.send(message)

    def recv(self):
        return self.parent_connection.recv()

    def __getstate__(self):
        return (self._parent_connection, self._child_connection)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self._parent_connection, self._child_connection = state

def keep_receiving(pipe):
    for i in range(3):
        print("from rec_proc: ", pipe)
        print(pipe.recv())

def keep_sending(pipe):
    for i in range(3):
        print("from send_proc:", pipe)
        pipe.send(text=f"test {i + 1}")
        time.sleep(1)

def v2():
    send_proc = Process(target=keep_sending, args=(MessagePipe(), ))
    send_proc.start()

    rec_proc = Process(target=keep_receiving, args=(MessagePipe(), ))
    rec_proc.start()

    send_proc.join()
    rec_proc.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    v2()
```

Prints:

```
__new__ is executing
__new__ is executing
__new__ is executing
from send_proc: <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x00000220220F15E0>
from rec_proc:  <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x000001BB2F5C15E0>
{'text': 'test 1', 'exception': None, 'level': 20}
from rec_proc:  <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x000001BB2F5C15E0>
from send_proc: <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x00000220220F15E0>
{'text': 'test 2', 'exception': None, 'level': 20}
from rec_proc:  <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x000001BB2F5C15E0>
from send_proc: <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x00000220220F15E0>
{'text': 'test 3', 'exception': None, 'level': 20}
```

Another, more classic implementation of the *singleton* pattern that does not use method `__new__` avoids creating new `Pipe` instances and their corresponding connections only to have them discarded by the `piclke` `__setstate__` method when it restores the original serialized connections:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import logging
import time

class MessagePipe:
    """This implements a multiprocessing message pipe as a singleton and is intended for passing event information
    such as log messaged and exceptions between processes.
    """

    _instance = None
    _parent_connection = None
    _child_connection = None

    def __init__(self):
        raise RuntimeError('Call getInstance() instead')

    @classmethod
    def getInstance(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            print('Creating new instance.')
            cls._instance = cls.__new__(cls)
            cls._parent_connection, cls._child_connection = Pipe()
        return cls._instance

    @property
    def child_connection(self):
        return self._child_connection

    @property
    def parent_connection(self):
        return self._parent_connection

    def send(self, text="", exception=None, level=logging.INFO):
        message = {
            "text": text,
            "exception": exception,
            "level": level
        }
        self.child_connection.send(message)

    def recv(self):
        return self.parent_connection.recv()

    def __getstate__(self):
        return (self._parent_connection, self._child_connection)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self._parent_connection, self._child_connection = state

def keep_receiving(pipe):
    for i in range(3):
        print("from rec_proc: ", pipe)
        print(pipe.recv())

def keep_sending(pipe):
    for i in range(3):
        print("from send_proc:", pipe)
        pipe.send(text=f"test {i + 1}")
        time.sleep(1)

def v2():
    send_proc = Process(target=keep_sending, args=(MessagePipe.getInstance(), ))
    send_proc.start()

    rec_proc = Process(target=keep_receiving, args=(MessagePipe.getInstance(), ))
    rec_proc.start()

    send_proc.join()
    rec_proc.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    v2()
```

Prints:

```
Creating new instance.
from send_proc: <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x0000023459610520>
from rec_proc:  <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x0000022F2D8A1520>
{'text': 'test 1', 'exception': None, 'level': 20}
from rec_proc:  <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x0000022F2D8A1520>
from send_proc: <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x0000023459610520>
{'text': 'test 2', 'exception': None, 'level': 20}
from rec_proc:  <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x0000022F2D8A1520>
from send_proc: <__mp_main__.MessagePipe object at 0x0000023459610520>
{'text': 'test 3', 'exception': None, 'level': 20}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am running Linux. If it were as you said about the fork stuff, wouldn't my `v1` work like my `v2` then? Regarding your question: In introduced this singleton to avoid a long argument-forwarding chain that would have been necessary with the non-singleton approach. But actually, if the reference to the Pipe from the calling process can be passed and used in a child process, then can a singleton not be established over processes in some way as well?

Comment: I actually wrote a follow-up question here, if you want to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70767697/pytest-incorrect-behavior-for-singletons-across-processes

Comment: No, no, no. A connection returned when you construct a `Pipe` can be serialized/deserialized with with no problem. But you are serializing an object that contains connections whose class has a `__new__` method that is re-creating those connections when it is deserialized and that is where your problem is -- your *singleton* implementation is inadequate for use with Windows multiprocessing. I even provided in code example 2 a remedy. But I must have done a very poor job in explaining. And why aren't you asking the person whose answer you accepted to look at your follow-up question?

Comment: I have updated the answer replacing code example 3, with another singleton pattern that does not use `__new__` and therefore avoids recreating the `Pipe` instances when deserializing under Windows. You still need to have the `pickle` `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods for proper serialization/deserialization of the *class* attributes.

Answer (score 1):

On any modern OS, these are *virtual memory* adresses. These addresses are local to each process' memory space. They almost never correspond to the same *physical memory* cell `0x7f805e769610`. You need to google "virtual memory"

Comment: That's not quite correct. See my comment to Serge Ballesta's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Modern OS use virtual memory. That means that physical memory pages are mapped into the process address space. Because of that, the loader can give to multiple instances of the same program the same virtual addresses. So in every process the singleton will have the same virtual address, but as those virtual addresses are mapped to different physical pages, they will point to distinct objects.

Comment: That's not quite right. It's only because os `fork` was used to create the new subprocess that the address is the same, i.e. because `pickle` did not have to be used to serialize/deserialize the arguments. Under Wndows, the address will be different and, in fact, the program will no longer run correctly because method \_\_new__ will be re-executed again in each new subprocess creating new Pipe instances.

Comment: You are right, but I can remember using `fork` on older systems and addresses were different in the child and the parent. And even *fork* has to use the kernel loader to load the new copy of the process. But it is true but on modern systems `fork` only has to copy the writable segments and map them on the same addresses which is much simpler...

Comment: @Booboo Which program would not run correctly under windows? `v1` already does not run under Linux (as expected; I was just confused why the addresses are the same) since every process has its own MessagePipe instance. `v2` should be correct, though.

Comment: @lotolmencre V2 will not run correctly under Windows (see my answer) -- it hangs and I thought I explained why. One more time: On Windows the argument to `keep_sending` and `keep_receiving` is sent using via serialization/deserialization using `pickle` and `MessagePipe.__new__` is re-executed *and* new instances of the `Pipe` instances are created. Look where I print out the '\_\_new__ is exeuting' message.