# Pytest: Incorrect behavior for singletons across processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, singleton, pytest

I had asked a question about singletons in different processes here: [Singleton has same address in multiple processes, but behaves like separate objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70758843/singleton-has-same-address-in-multiple-processes-but-behaves-like-separate-obje#70758908)

I wrote a test that I expected to fail. But is does not fail when run with pytest. However, it does hang when run with python directly, **which is expected**. Is this a bug in pytest? Since this should not work.

Test code:

```
def test_messages_sent_from_two_processes_are_received_at_same_parent_connector():

    def send_dummy(dummy):
        MessagePipe().send(dummy)

    def receive_dummy(target_dummy, return_dict):
        return_dict[target_dummy] = receive_message()["text"]

    return_dict = Manager().dict()

    text1 = "dummy1"
    text2 = "dummy2"

    p1 = Process(target=send_dummy, args=(text1, ))
    p2 = Process(target=send_dummy, args=(text2, ))
    p3 = Process(target=receive_dummy, args=(text1, return_dict))
    p4 = Process(target=receive_dummy, args=(text2, return_dict))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()

    assert all(k == v for k, v in return_dict.items())
```

Implementation of the singleton pipe class and functions:

```
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pipe


class MessagePipe:
    """This implements a multiprocessing message pipe as a singleton and is intended for passing event information
    such as log messaged and exceptions between processes.
    """

    _instance = None
    _parent_connection = None
    _child_connection = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(MessagePipe, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._parent_connection, cls._child_connection = Pipe()
        return cls._instance

    @property
    def child_connection(self):
        return self._child_connection

    @property
    def parent_connection(self):
        return self._parent_connection

    def send(self, text="", exception=None, level=logging.INFO):
        message = {
            "text": text,
            "exception": exception,
            "level": level
        }
        self.child_connection.send(message)

    def recv(self):
        return self.parent_connection.recv()


def send_message(**kwargs):
    MessagePipe().send(**kwargs)


def receive_message():
    return MessagePipe().recv()
```

Comment: A `Pipe` (or should I say its connections?) is meant to be a single producer/single consumer communications pathway unless you build "scaffolding" on top of it to ensure serial access (a `multiprocessing.SimpleQueue` is essentially a *locked* `Pipe` and a `multiprocessing.Queue` adds a buffer of size N and a thread that will take from the buffer and send to the pipe's connection so as to implement a pipe of size N). The point is: what you are doing is *non-deterministic*. It succeeds or fails according to whether `sends` and `recvs` are done concurrently or not. (more...)

Comment: My guess is that `pytest` somehow indirectly ensures serialization of the calls to `send` and the calls to `recv`. Or that has just been the case coincidentally and the next time it will fail under `pytest`. I would not lose sleep over this, for what you are doing is illegal **and you know that** and just because it is working in one scenario (unfortunately, the test scenario) doesn't make it right. Just don't do it since you know better.

Comment: I just realized that the singleton, `MessagePipe()` is *not* being created by the main process but rather *four singletons* are being created, one each in your subprocesses that you are creating. So this program is not correct and should hang even if you added locking on sending and receiving to ensure serial access to the connections because each process is talking to unpaired connections. So I really have no idea what you mean by this is working with `pytest`.

Comment: I mean just that: It works "correctly" with Pytest, even though it should not. The test does not fail. But it should.

Comment: What are you actually testing? That it completes?

Comment: Well, that the assert passes

Comment: It will pass if there are *no keys* at all. Print out the dictionary to see what is in it. But I don't see how you get past the `join` calls.

Comment: Yes, that is my confusion exactly.

Comment: Add try/catch blocks to your subprocesses. If they are throwing an exception, you would not know it

Answer (score 0):

See my comments. The important one is duplicated here more or less:

> The singleton, MessagePipe() is not being created by the main process but rather four singletons are being created, one each in your subprocesses that you are creating. So this program is not correct and should hang even if you added locking on sending and receiving to ensure serial access to the connections because each process is talking to unpaired connections. So I really have no idea what you mean by this is working with pytest.

So I have no explanation as to how this would not hang in any scenario since you have 4 sets of pipes being created and thus 4 sets of connections. To get this to work, you must ensure serial access to the connections by using `multiprocessing.Lock` instances. But even then, when you have two tasks doing `recv` calls, you cannot be sure which call will be satisfied first and therefore what the key/value pairs will end up being. So your final assertion cannot be made.

Note that this code only works on platforms that use *fork* to create new processes:

```py
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Lock, Manager, Process


class MessagePipe:
    """This implements a multiprocessing message pipe as a singleton and is intended for passing event information
    such as log messaged and exceptions between processes.
    """

    _instance = None
    _parent_connection = None
    _parent_connection_lock = None
    _child_connection = None
    _child_connection_lock = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            print('Creating new instance.')
            cls._instance = super(MessagePipe, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._parent_connection, cls._child_connection = Pipe()
            cls._parent_connection_lock, cls._child_connection_lock = Lock(), Lock()
        return cls._instance

    @property
    def child_connection(self):
        return self._child_connection

    @property
    def parent_connection(self):
        return self._parent_connection

    def send(self, text="", exception=None, level=logging.INFO):
        message = {
            "text": text,
            "exception": exception,
            "level": level
        }
        with self._child_connection_lock:
            self.child_connection.send(message)

    def recv(self):
        with self._parent_connection_lock:
            return self.parent_connection.recv()


def test_messages_sent_from_two_processes_are_received_at_same_parent_connector():

    def send_dummy(message_pipe, dummy):
        message_pipe.send(dummy)

    def receive_dummy(message_pipe, target_dummy, return_dict):
        return_dict[target_dummy] = message_pipe.recv()["text"]

    return_dict = Manager().dict()

    text1 = "dummy1"
    text2 = "dummy2"

    p1 = Process(target=send_dummy, args=(MessagePipe(), text1))
    p2 = Process(target=send_dummy, args=(MessagePipe(), text2))
    p3 = Process(target=receive_dummy, args=(MessagePipe(), text1, return_dict))
    p4 = Process(target=receive_dummy, args=(MessagePipe(), text2, return_dict))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()

    # You cannot control which recv task will retrieve which message:
    #assert all(k == v for k, v in return_dict.items())
    print(return_dict)

test_messages_sent_from_two_processes_are_received_at_same_parent_connector()
```

Prints:

```
Creating new instance.
{'dummy2': 'dummy1', 'dummy1': 'dummy2'}
```

Comment: I know that it is non-deterministic. But the `recv` calls should hang, which they do not.

Comment: I agree and I have no explanation. Sorry.